# Should I reuse service for calendar API, or is it safe to create new ones on demand?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api

I've made a small web server that creates and updates calendar events. However, I'm a bit uncertain about how I'm supposed to use the calendar api library service. At the moment I'm creating a new one each time the web server accepts a request, like so:

```
ctx := context.Background()
srv, err := calendar.NewService(ctx,option.WithTokenSource(config.TokenSource(ctx)))
```

I suspect I'm probably supposed to reuse this service, but I can't find any documentation about this. Is it safe to reuse? Does it get discarded automatically when no longer in use (i.e. garbage collection)?

Comment: is the api safe for concurrent use ? then you can re use the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `req.Context()` (where `req` is your `*http.Request`) instead of `context.Background()`. In this case, you have to create a new service object each time, and they will be garbage collected as appropriate.

The only reason you would want to use `context.Background()` is if you're asynchronously issuing the calendar API requests (eg, in a separate goroutine) and they might not finish before the HTTP request finishes. In this case, you could use a single shared service object if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying answer :)